# I keep getting Global name 'username' not defined?

Tags: python, global-variables, undefined, global

My issue us that I keep getting a global name not defined error in this script:

```
import time
def cls():
    print(("\n")*100)
#Registers the Username and Password for the user.
def registerPro():
    cls()
    username=str(input("Enter your Username here: "))
    password=str(input("Enter your Password here: "))
    confirm=str(input("Please confirm your Password: "))
    if password==confirm:
        cls()
        print("Thank you for registering at Apex Industries!")
        time.sleep(3)
        loggingIn()
    else:
        cls()
        print("Your passwords do not match, please re-register.")
        time.sleep(3)
        registerPro()
    return username, password
#Is called by getUsername. If the user entered the password correctly then the login is successful.
def getPass(password):
    cls()
    confirmPass=str(input("Enter your password: "))
    if confirmPass==password:
        cls()
        print("You have logged in successfully.")
    else:
        cls()
        print("Wrong Password. Try again")
        getPass()
#Makes sure the username is in the database.
def getUsername(username):
    cls()
    confirmUser=str(input("Enter your username: "))
    if confirmUser==username:
        getPass(password)
    else:
        cls()
        print("No username with that name in the database.")
        time.sleep(3)
        loggingIn()
#The login for the main program.
def loggingIn():
    cls()
    print("Hello and welcome to the Apex Industries login/register page.")
    print("      Please choose to either Login or Register.")
    print()
    regLog=str(input("Type Login or Register for your choice: "))
    if regLog=='Login':
        getUsername(username)
    elif regLog=='Register':
        registerPro()
    else:
        cls()
        print("That is not a valid option. Try again.")
        time.sleep(3)
        loggingIn()

loggingIn()
```

My traceback gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Evu/Desktop/Python/testforLogin", line 59, in <module>
    loggingIn()
  File "C:/Users/Evu/Desktop/Python/testforLogin", line 13, in loggingIn
    registerPro()
  File "C:/Users/Evu/Desktop/Python/testforLogin", line 29, in registerPro
    loggingIn()
  File "C:/Users/Evu/Desktop/Python/testforLogin", line 11, in loggingIn
    getUsername(username)
NameError: global name 'username' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to import username into the getUsername() function I have created. Keep in mind that I am new to scripting and am just trying to learn this on my own time, this is just a test script. Any advice would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `getUsername` function with a variable called `username` as an argument, which is not defined at that point.
In fact, it gets defined within the `getUsername` function, but not as `username` either. Instead what ends up being the variable containing the real username is `confirmUser`. That kind of makes sense in that case, but then `username` should contain the username which is valid / registered. That in turn actually should be some kind of list containing more than just one username, for which a dedicated function would be a possible way to go.

The funny thing: you did it correctly in the beginning with the regLog-thing. There you're defining regLog via input, and afterwards checking its value.

You definitely should have a second look on the documentation regarding variables, functions (and their arguments), the basics in general. Oh, and it should be `raw_input()` instead of `input()`. In this case at least.

This would be my quick and dirty (and incomplete) approach:

```
registeredusers = ['john.doe', 'peter.parker', 'bruce.banner']

def getUsername():
    global registeredusers
    loginname = str(raw_input("Enter username: "))
    if loginname in registeredusers:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def loggingIn():
    regLog = str(raw_input("Login or Register? "))
    if regLog == 'Login':
        if getUsername():
            print "Yay! Logged in"
        else:
            print "Login failed"
    elif regLog == 'Register':
        # do stuff
        pass
    else:
        # do stuff
        pass

loggingIn()
```

Comment: So how would I implement this into my own script? For example how would I get the variable to be defined globally instead of only within registerPro()? Do I have to move things around? Add something else? Also what is the different between raw_input and input?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialised username when you make the call in `loggingIn()` to `getUsername(username)` - which username are you trying to validate, where is it coming from? Given it can't find a local `username` it looks in the global namespace and can't find it there - hence the error.